# Pizza Ordering Program (v2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a phone order pizza ordering program for my Digital Tech assignment. I would appreciate feedback on the code quality (increasing efficiency, whilst maintaining readability). The full code is runnable on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GjNe/85), and is also pasted below.

This is a repost with an updated version of my code for review. Pizza Ordering Program v1 is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159588/pizza-ordering-program). Compared to v1, I have capitalized the constants, and moved the logic to inside the Order class, simplifying the actual run loop.

**The full, working code is below:**

```
"""Onehunga Pizzas phone orders"""

import re
import sys

# CONFIG #
# maximum number of pizzas in one order
MAX_PIZZAS = 5
# delivery charge (in $)
DELIVERY_CHARGE = 3.00
# list of dictionaries (pizzas) with name and price
PIZZAS_AVAILABLE = (
    {"name": "Hawaiian",             "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Meat Lovers",          "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Pepperoni",            "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Ham & Cheese",         "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Classic Cheese",       "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Veg Hot 'n' Spicy",    "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Beef & Onion",         "price": 8.5},
    {"name": "Seafood Deluxe",       "price": 13.5},
    {"name": "Summer Shrimp",        "price": 13.5},
    {"name": "BBQ Bacon & Mushroom", "price": 13.5},
    {"name": "BBQ Hawaiian",         "price": 13.5},
    {"name": "Italiano",             "price": 13.5},
)
# END CONFIG #


def get_input(regex, input_message=None, error_message=None):
    """Gets valid input, validated using regular expressions."""
    # loops until input is valid ("break" is called)
    while True:
        # input to validate, input prompt is as specified
        if input_message:
            user_input = input(str(input_message))
        else:
            user_input = input()
        user_input = user_input.lower().strip()
        # check if the user wants to quit or cancel the order
        if user_input == "qq" or user_input == "quit":
            sys.exit()
        elif user_input == "cc" or user_input == "cancel":
            return "CANCEL"

        # check if the input matches the regex provided
        if re.match(regex, user_input, re.IGNORECASE):
            break

        # if it doesn't match, and an error message has been specified
        if error_message:
            print(str(error_message))

    return user_input


def print_line(line):
    """ Prints "| <message> |". Used for print_order()."""
    print("| {:54} |".format(line))


def print_order(order):
    """Prints the order details to the screen"""
    print_line("Name: " + order.name)
    print_line("Order type: " + ("Pickup" if order.pickup else "Delivery"))
    if not order.pickup:
        print_line("Delivery address: " + order.address)
        print_line("Customer phone number: " + order.phone)
    print_line("")
    print_line("Order summary:{:15}Price each:{:5}Subtotal:".format("", ""))
    for pizza in order.pizzas:
        print_line("{:5}x {:22}{:5}${:5.2f}{:8}${:>5.2f}".format(
            pizza["amount"], pizza["name"], "",
            pizza["price"], "", pizza["price"]*pizza["amount"]))
    if not order.pickup:
        print_line("{:4}Delivery charge{:29}${:>5.2f}".format(
            "", "", DELIVERY_CHARGE))

    print_line("{:48}------".format(""))
    print_line("{:40} Total: ${:.2f}".format("", order.cost))


class Order():
    """Holds each order's information, can get the information itself."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.pickup = False
        self.address = None
        self.phone = None
        self.pizzas = []
        self.cost = 0

    def get_pickup(self):
        user_input = get_input(
            r"$|(?:P|D)",
            "Pickup or delivery? [Pickup]:",
            "Please enter a 'p' (pickup) or a 'd' (delivery)")
        if user_input == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        self.pickup = user_input.lower().startswith("p") or not user_input

    def get_name(self):
        user_input = get_input(
            r"[A-Z]+$",
            "Enter customer name:",
            "Name must only contain letters")
        if user_input == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        self.name = user_input[:48]

    def get_address(self):
        user_input = get_input(
            r"[ -/\w]+$",
            "Delivery address:",
            "Address must only contain alphanumeric characters")
        if user_input == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        self.address = user_input[:36]

    def get_phone(self):
        user_input = get_input(
            r"\d+$",
            "Phone number:",
            "Phone number must only contain numbers")
        if user_input == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        self.phone = user_input[:11]

    def get_pizzas(self):
        # loop to get valid input, needs to be more specific than
        # just regex (needs to be greater than 0, less than 5)
        while True:
            user_input = get_input(
                r"\d$",
                "Number of pizzas to order:",
                "Must be a digit, 5 or less")
            if user_input == "CANCEL":
                return "CANCEL"

            if 0 < int(user_input) <= MAX_PIZZAS:
                number_pizzas = int(user_input)
                break
            else:
                print("Must be a digit, 5 or less (but more than 0)")

        print("\nWhat pizzas would you like to order?")
        for i, pizza in enumerate(PIZZAS_AVAILABLE):
            # each pizza's number is its index (i) + 1,
            # so the first pizza is 1
            print("{}: {}".format(str(i+1).zfill(2), pizza["name"]))

        print("\nEnter your selection number for each pizza you want to buy")
        for i in range(number_pizzas):
            # loop to get valid input
            while True:
                user_input = get_input(
                    r"\d\d?$",
                    "Pizza #{} of {}:".format(i+1, number_pizzas),
                    "Pizza selection number must "
                    "correspond to those listed above")
                if user_input == "CANCEL":
                    return "CANCEL"

                try:
                    # 0 is not a valid pizza number
                    if int(user_input) == 0:
                        raise IndexError
                    # selects the pizza based on user_input
                    # gives IndexError if not valid (e.g. 23 is not valid)
                    to_add = PIZZAS_AVAILABLE[int(user_input)-1]

                except IndexError:
                    print("Pizza selection number must "
                          "correspond to those listed above")

                # if there has been no error,
                else:
                    # input is valid, break from the while loop
                    break

            # if the pizza has already been ordered,
            # increment the amount ordered
            for ordered in self.pizzas:
                if to_add["name"] == ordered["name"]:
                    ordered["amount"] += 1
                    break
            # else add the pizza to the order list
            else:
                to_add["amount"] = 1
                order.pizzas.append(to_add)

    def get_cost(self):
        cost = sum(
            pizza["price"]*pizza["amount"]
            for pizza in self.pizzas)
        if not self.pickup:
            cost += DELIVERY_CHARGE
        self.cost = cost

    def get_details(self):
        if self.get_pickup() == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        if self.get_name() == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        if not self.pickup:
            if self.get_address() == "CANCEL":
                return "CANCEL"
            if self.get_phone() == "CANCEL":
                return "CANCEL"
        if self.get_pizzas() == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"
        if self.get_cost() == "CANCEL":
            return "CANCEL"


# if __name__ == "__main__":
if __name__ == "builtins":  # for repl.it
    print(
        "== Onehunga Pizzas ==\n"
        "==  Order Manager  ==\n"
        "Enter 'CC' to cancel order, or 'QQ' to exit program at any time.\n"
        "The first letter of a word is usually only required as input.\n"
        "A word [enclosed] in brackets is the default option.\n")

    # list to hold all completed orders
    orders = []

    # sorts pizza list by price, then alphabetically
    PIZZAS_AVAILABLE = sorted(
        PIZZAS_AVAILABLE,
        key=lambda k: (k["price"], k["name"]))

    # loop to get orders until told to quit (quits through sys.exit)
    while True:
        order = Order()
        if not order.get_details() == "CANCEL":
            print("\nOrder saved. Order was:")
            print_order(order)
            orders.append(order)
        else:
            print("\nOrder cancelled.")

        user_input = get_input(
            r"$|(?:Y|N|O).*",
            "Would you like to enter another order or view all "
            "previous orders? [Yes]/No/Orders:",
            "Only yes/no or \"orders\" responses allowed")
        if user_input.lower().startswith("n"):
            sys.exit()
        elif user_input.lower().startswith("o"):
            # print orders
            for i, order in enumerate(orders):
                # make nice box around orders, special title at top
                if i == 0:
                    print("-"*23 + " ALL ORDERS " + "-"*23)
                else:
                    print("|" + "-"*56 + "|")
                print_order(order)
                # if it is the last order, close the box
                if i == len(orders) - 1:
                    print("-" * 58)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations and suggestions:

- I think you can either define the `PIZZAS_AVAILABLE` in the correct expected order or sort right after defining it instead of sorting it inside the main execution block
- you can remove redundant `()` after the class name:

  ```
  class Order:
  ```
- you can use the inline if/else for the `user_input` variable:

  ```
  user_input = input(str(input_message) if input_message else '')
  ```

  or, even better - define the default `input_message` value as an empty string. Then, you would be able to do:

  ```
  user_input = input(str(input_message)).lower().strip()
  ```
- instead of defining a separate `print_order()` function, consider defining the `__str__()` magic method on the `Order` class. Then, you'll be able to do:

  ```
  print(order)
  ```

  where `order` is an instance of the `Order` class
- I don't particularly like the overall design of the `Order` class - it is currently tied to the user inputs that come from the multiple `get_input()` calls which makes the user interaction logic scattered across the whole program. Not sure how big of an issue this is, but I would expect the `Order` class to be agnostic of where the order data is coming from (referring to [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))
- the `get_details()` is probably not the best name for a method that is checking if an order should be canceled or not
- consider defining `pickup`, `name` and other things you get via `get_*()` methods as [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I'd completely forgotten about`__str__`. Would you recommend moving the input logic out of the class and into separate functions? `get_details` is supposed to run all the `get_*` functions and get all the order's details. I have to be able to cancel the order at any time, the cancel will be entered as input, and somehow needs to get back to my get orders loop. That's what all the `if x == "CANCEL"` are for. If I was to define the `get_*` as properties, wouldn't the Order class still have the input logic in it? If input is invalid, it immediately needs retry until valid.

Comment: https://repl.it/GjNe/92 Updated to fit points 1, 2, 3 &4

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt yes, it would be great to move the input validation logic from outside of the `Order` class.  About `get_details()` - yeah, you are right. In this case, I'd still improve that "if canceled" check, since it is not immediately obvious that aside from checking if an order is canceled, you also grab the order information..I would probably post a separate follow-up question for the second round of reviews, or wait if there will be other answers with other points..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a small one, but I believe it would make more sense for `PIZZAS_AVAILABLE` to be a `dict` and not a `tuple`:

```
PIZZAS_AVAILABLE = {
    "Hawaiian": 8.5,
    "Meat Lovers": 8.5,
    "Pepperoni": 8.5
    ...
}
```